# c# scripting vs c# programming

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently learning C# and I have decided to try to make a few simple games in Unity to keep motivation up while learning.

I noticed that in Unity you write C# scripts for player movement etc. not C# programs? What's the difference, if any?

I don't need a long explanation just pros and cons.
I don't want to get used to making games in Unity just to find out it's completely different from writing C# programs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Be aware, a) unity uses mono. b) the version of .net it runs is version 2. c) some parts of .net are simply not supported like HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse which will simply never fire the call back in Unity.

Answer (score 4):

C# *scripting* is just a term. It just means that C# programming language is used. In Unity3D, you can either use Javascript, Boo or C#. They just labeled these languages as "script".

In terms of syntax, there should be no difference. But in terms of the API's used, it could differ depending on what Unity3D is using from the usual .NET framework.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as C# scripts.

While I don't know Unity, I assume that it simply takes those "Scripts" and compiles them into a dynamic DLL.

Comment: "There is no such thing as C# scripts" well at least for now, when Roslyn will be officially released it will be possible to make c# script.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini: How is that? It will still not be interpreted.

Comment: aw, what a pity. Thank you anyway I dind't know that

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend learning C# in a non-unity setting as well as in unity, because it'll help you understand how different paradigms can work.

The basic syntax & api's are the same - however the frameworks and paradigms are very different.